# even-sided cyclic polygons

Tags: geometry

It's just a matter of angle-chasing to show the following:
Extend the sides of a convex quadrilateral.
Draw the in-circles of the triangles (open or not) defined by an original side and the extended adjacent sides.
Their centres are concyclic.

Having produced the first cyclic quadrilateral we can iterate the construction.

Playing with Geometer's Sketchpad suggests that, if we begin with any even-sided cyclic polygon and perform the same construction, the in-circle centres will always define a cyclic polygon.

Am I right? Can anyone prove/disprove the conjecture?

By dissecting the polygons into quadrilaterals sharing a vertex we can show that alternate angle sums are equal, a condition sufficient in the case of the quadrilateral itself but I suspect not in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

The conjecture does not hold. For a cyclic hexagon, by [Poncelet's porism](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PonceletsPorism.html) the six incenters may lie on the same conic, but such a conic is not always a circle. In the following configuration, the incenter conic (in blue) is an ellipse:

[image: A counterexample to the conjecture]

Comment: I didn't make clear that the starting polygon has to be cyclic. (it just happens that, in the case of a quadrilateral, it only has to be convex.) I shouldn't have presented the problem the way I did.

Comment: @PaulStephenson: OK, I fixed the counterexample.

Comment: That's very nice. Thank you Jack D'Aurizio.

Comment: Members may be interested to iterate the construction. In the case of the quadrilaterals, you can show that they converge on the square. Is it the case for the general even-sided polygons that the conic they define converges on the circle as they converge on their regular form?